# Determining required signal SNR (beat signal from FMCW RADAR)

Tags: signal, microwave, signal-to-noise, snr

I'm trying to determine the SNR required for signal outcoming from FMCW Radar.
This is the chain: signal will created by "24 GHz VCO and PGA with 2-Channel PA Output" by triangle shape frequency domain, 8 dBm,250 max range.

Then received in this manner:

- 4ch 24GHz receiver downconverter ->
- RADAR receiver path AFE: 4CH LNA & PGA ->
- (Op-Amp) summer of 4ch together ->
- (Op-Amp) sallen-key filter ->
- Transmit to other board

Note: The AD817s Negative voltages is created by switching inverting regulator!

Seems I need to start through PA power then add max distance noise to it, then noise of receivers chain through their datasheet. Then some MATLAB simulation to determine least possible SNR required?

Comment: or work backwards from required SNR on on acceleration, velocity and position.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist explain more plz, it's ambiguous for me.

Comment: Define output resolution and noise SNR 1st, then work backwards to required carrier/noise ratio. CNR.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I think your approach require tunable power output, but at this design transmitting power is not controllable.

Comment: Then you can compute max, path loss

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist How to model ambient gaussian or other noise (and I Think multipath is not problem in 250m range constraint)? and how resolution correlate to SNR?

Comment: The required signal to noise ratio comes from your required probability of detection and allowable probability of false alarm.  Once you have those, you can determine how much SNR is required.  Then you can run your standard radar range equation.  But be careful to consider phase noise, not just awg noise!

Comment: @MikeP Exactly what is phase noise source?